# Opening new window in WebDriver using C#

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

**EDIT 4:**

[image]
**EDIT 3**
[image]

**EDIT 2**

```
    string currentWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

    driver.SwitchTo().Window("");
    string childTitle = driver.Title;

    driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentWindow);
    string parentTitle = driver.Title;
```

the above code gives me the same title for parent window or child window.

EDIT:

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_Features_ctl03_lnkPage" class="title" target="_blank" href="websiteaddress">Stay  Around</a>
```

how to verify the title of a newly window open and once i verified then close the opened new window?

so in my page I have a link and click on the link and it opens a new window and now I am not sure how to verify the title of that window.

here is what i have done so far.

```
GoToMysiteUrl();
IWebElement addtoList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(_pageName));
addtoList.Click();
```

//it opens a new window

now i want to switch focus on the new window and verify the title and close the new window
back to the previous window.

Comment: The edits obscure the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece that most people miss when dealing with popup windows in IE is that a click on an element is asynchronous. That is to say, if you check the `.WindowHandles` property immediately after a click, you may lose the race condition, because you're checking for the existence of a new window before IE has had the chance to create it, and the driver has had a chance to register it exists.

Here's the C# code I would use to perform the same operation:

```
string foundHandle = null;
string originalWindowHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

// Get the list of existing window handles.
IList<string> existingHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
IWebElement addtoList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(_pageName));
addtoList.Click();

// Use a timeout. Alternatively, you could use a WebDriverWait
// for this operation.
DateTime timeout = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
while(DateTime.Now < timeout)
{
    // This method uses LINQ, so it presupposes you are running on
    // .NET 3.5 or above. Alternatively, it's possible to do this
    // without LINQ, but the code is more verbose.
    IList<string> currentHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
    IList<string> differentHandles = currentHandles.Except(existingHandles).ToList();
    if (differentHandles.Count > 0)
    {
        // There will ordinarily only be one handle in this list,
        // so it should be safe to return the first one here.
        foundHandle = differentHandles[0];
        break;
    }

    // Sleep for a very short period of time to prevent starving the driver thread.
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(foundHandle))
{
    throw new Exception("didn't find popup window within timeout");
}

driver.SwitchToWindow(foundHandle);

// Do whatever verification on the popup window you need to, then...
driver.Close();

// And switch back to the original window handle.
driver.SwitchToWindow(originalWindowHandle);
```

Incidentally, if you're using the .NET bindings, you have access to a `PopupWindowFinder` class in the WebDriver.Support.dll assembly, which uses a very similar approach to the locating popup windows. You may find that class meets your needs exactly, and can use it without modification.

Comment: Thanks Jim after implementing your code I'm getting `No window found` on the last line `driver.SwitchTo().Window(foundHandle);`

Comment: What is the value of originalWindowHandle and foundHandle? are they the same? If you step through your code in the debugger (after the .Click(), don't set your breakpoint before you click on the element), can you diagnose better what's happening?

Comment: `[0] "1bd949f4-12c9-4098-ac53-83cb82ea8cd7"` `[1] "de35fb9c-990f-497e-866e-98a87c90d12e"` i found two windowHandle

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look at EDIT 3 & 4, i see that i have two windows open (parent and a new window)

Comment: And after subtracting out the existing windows, do you only have one window? If so, I can only think of two causes. First, that you have an interstitial window that opens and closes before the "real" popup window opens. Second, that you're using the `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings` option when launching the driver. Aside from that, there are many tests that are able to switch to a popup window without issue, including in the tests for the WebDriver project itself.

Comment: yes after subtracting out the existing windows i see only one window handle and i also make sure that the id i am getting is the new window id and which is.

Comment: i did not get your last pat of your reply so what does it mean?

Comment: Many people try to avoid setting the Protected Mode settings of IE by using the capabilities when instantiating the IE driver. This is the Wrong Thing to do, and you should take the time to set the Protected Mode settings of IE if you're able. See more [here](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html)

Comment: I have not control over it changing the settings and this is something done by the organization and i try to go to IE==>Options==>Security - i see its disabled by administrator and even if ask them to enable Admin folks will never do that for me... so what is the alternate?

Comment: Point your administrators to that blog post is the best I can suggest. Crossing a Protected Mode boundary without the zones being set to the same value will have unpredictable results. The capability **is** the workaround, but it's not guaranteed to work at all.

Comment: hmm.... i am the administrator on the machine which i am working on and the message says `some settings are managed by your system administrator` the checkbox [] enable protected mode is disabled.... what about this code ` var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                    options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
                    _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);` i tried but does not work.... ergggg

Comment: That's exactly the code that's **not** guaranteed to work. You'll need to work with your IT department to resolve the issue.

Comment: @JimEvans how can i get handle to current window(existing Window which is opened manually) which is not opened by driver means i can't use driver.getWindowHandle();

Answer (score 0):

```
GoToMysiteUrl();
IWebElement addtoList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(_pageName));
addtoList.Click();
```

// Post above operation a new window would open as described in problem

// Get hold of Main window's handle

```
string  currentWindow = Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
```

// Switch to the newly opened window

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Window("Your Window Name");
```

// Perform required Actions/Assertions here and close the window

// Switch to Main window

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentWindow);
```

Comment: How do I know my window name?

Comment: Take a look at the link that opened your window:

<a href="somewhere.html" target="windowName">Click here to open a new window</a>

    Driver.SwitchTo().Window("windowName");

Comment: Try giving blank value as Driver.SwitchTo().Window(""); I tried with following url and it did work for me. http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET_95y98y108y97y110y107y.html

Comment: hmm.. i have updated my question again and i am unable to switch the window i guess and i am trying to get the Title of the page and i am getting the same title name for both (parent and child window) i have updated my question, have a look at it please.