# No window found - NoSuchWindowException was unhandled

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting an error which says `No Window found` I'm trying to Switch to window and below is the code i am using.

```
        VisitMyWebSite();

        string originalHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

        IWebElement addtoList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(_pageName));
        addtoList.Click();

        ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
        string popupHandle = string.Empty;

        foreach (string handle in windowHandles)
        {
            if (handle != originalHandle)
            {
                popupHandle = handle; break;
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(4000);

        //switch to new window 
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupHandle);  //error No Window found
```

Comment: That's some cool code, but what is your question?

Comment: Can you describe the scenario that youre failing in?  i.e.: I have 3 windows open, with 3 different names, etc.  It doesnt look like your code handles having only one window open, or having multiple instances of the 'original' window open, are either of those two scenarios happening?  For instance, if you only have 1 window open, popupHandle is never going to get reset so youll be trying to navigate to an empty string...

Comment: please have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244448/opening-new-window-in-webdriver-using-c-sharp