# Handeling popup window in selenium c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My program includes many windows.
Whenever I want to change the first window (I named "bigwindow") and the new second window
I have been using the following code in order to switch betwing the windows:

```
Ireadonlycollection <string> openwindows1=driver.windowhandels;
    Foreach (string current in openwindows1)
     {
         If (current!= bigwindow)
          {
               Driver.switchto().window(current):
               Break
           }
      }
```

I trying to using this code when a popup window was opened from the second window and it is not working.. 
The focus is still on the second window and not on the third..
Please help me

Comment: that popup is child window? OR Iframe?

Comment: Child window ... it is opened as a new popup window

Comment: See if this help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244448/opening-new-window-in-webdriver-using-c-sharp